# Racket match semantics with null

Tags: pattern-matching, racket

My question is why the following pattern returns `'match` even though `(make-tree 0 null null)` is clearly not null?

```
#lang racket
(define-struct tree (val left right))
(match (make-tree 1 (make-tree 0 null null) null)
  [(tree 1 null _) 'match]
  [_ 'no-match])
```

I noticed changing the `null` to `'()` in the first pattern yields the correct(?) value. Why does this occur? Aren't `null` and `'()` equivalent? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html, identifiers in patterns has the following rule:

> `id` or `(var id)` — matches anything, and binds `id` to the matching values.

In your case, `null` is not evaluated to a value. Instead, it is recognized as an identifier shadowed by the value matched at that position, which is `(make-tree 0 null null)`

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, a bare identifier will match anything because the purpose of an identifier in a match pattern is to create a new binding as a result of the match. Of course, `null` is not a keyword in Racket, it’s just a binding exported by `racket/base`, so it just gets bound as usual. In contrast, `'()` is a quoted list literal, which can obviously be detected by `match` and handled accordingly.

It is sometimes useful, though, to be able to compare values dynamically, in which case those values will be bound to identifiers. In this case, you can use the `==` match expander, which will compare the match to the value of an arbitrary expression. This would allow you to use `null` if you wished:

```
#lang racket
(define-struct tree (val left right))
(match (make-tree 1 (make-tree 0 null null) null)
  [(tree 1 (== null) _) 'match]
  [_ 'no-match])
; => 'no-match
```

Of course, using `'()` is probably clearer in this case.

Comment: Thank you. The comment about null not being a keyword was good to know.